# Simple XCode Storyboard scrolling text box?

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I am trying to use Xcode to produce a simple app that displays a handbook as a series of buttons leading to pages of text. My problem is that when I create a text view and populate it with my text, the simulator view cuts off the end of the text and does not allow me to scroll downwards.
Is there a simple solution without resorting to code? I tried initially to write the whole thing in code form, but ground to a halt fairly quickly!

I tried using a scroll view, and then creating a text view inside it, but I don't see any scroll bars or movement - I suspect Im missing a fairly basic linking move?

Any help appreciated,

Regards,

BW

Answer (score 0):

Theres a code end to making a scrollView functional, implement something like the following and link to your interface.

```
[myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
```

Comment: I can't seem to edit the files with the assistant editor - I get "UIViewController.h is locked for editing"

Comment: you add this to your view controller or what ever you're using. Not to the framework.